# Pivot Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to pivot a table and am having a bit of difficulty. My table schema looks like this:

```
ID  W_C    W_P      A_C   A_P
3   257    251342   217   206078
4   443    109023   332   87437
6   17     9985     32    13515
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something to the effect of:

```
        3       4       6
w_c     257     443     17
w_p     251342  109023  9985
a_c     217     332     87437
a_p     206078  87437   13515
```

I do not need to display the `w_c`, `w_p`, `a_c`, or `a_p` I just was using it as a point of reference.

I think there may be a way of doing it with pivot/unpivot but I am not very familiar with them, and what I have read isn't helping me.

I tried doing something using CTE's but I believe it is overly complicated and is just bad practice:

```
;with [3_Data] as (
    Select
        1 as [common_key3]
        ,max(Case when [id] = 3 then [w_c] else 0 end) as [3_Records]
    From [example]
), [4_data] as (
Select
        1 as [common_key4]
        ,max(Case when [id] = 4 then [w_c] else 0 end) as [4_Records]
    From [example]
), [6_data] as (
    Select
        1 as [common_key6]
        ,max(Case when [id] = 6 then [w_c] else 0 end) as [6_Records]
    From [example]
)
Select [3_Records], [4_Records], [6_Records]
From [3_Data]
    inner join [4_data] on [common_key3] = [common_key4]
    inner join [6_data] on [common_key3] = [common_key6]
```

Sql fiddle with table already created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02ef2/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and then a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the result you want (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/477b6/5)):

```
select col, [3], [4], [6]
from
(
  select id, value, col
  from
  (
    select id, w_c, w_p, a_c, a_p
    from t
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (w_c, w_p, a_c, a_p)
  )u
) x1
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for id in ([3], [4], [6])
) p
```

In this query you will first, `UNPIVOT` which will allow you easier access to the data to transform. You can use whatever names you want for the `value` and `col` fields, I just chose that for this example. Once the data is unpivoted, you can then apply a `PIVOT` to get the final product.

Comment: @Brad happy to help, one thing to keep in mind is if you have a lot of columns, you can write this as a dynamic query as well